# or with regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

let's say I have this code:

```
var pattern = /^\d{1}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;

//var res = pattern.replace("-", ".");
```

how can you not make it mandatory for the user to not always use a dash when inputting a number? I wanted to let the input a dash or a dot...

Comment: Do you mean `var pattern = /^\d[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}$/;`? Or `var pattern = /^\d([-.]?)\d{3}\1\d{3}\1\d{4}$/;`? Please let me know if that works fror you so that I could post with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a `?` quantifier after them to make the dashes optional:

```
var pattern = /^\d[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}$/;
```

Here, `[-.]?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of a `-` or `.` character.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JdYyYD/1).

If you want to require a *consistent* way of entering data, use grouping and backreferences:

```
/^\d([-.]?)\d{3}\1\d{3}\1\d{4}$/;
```

See the same [demo fiddle with this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/JdYyYD/2).

Here, `([-.]?)` forms a capturing group with ID 1, and `\1` is a backreference to the value stored in the Group 1 memory buffer. So, if the first group matched `.`, all `\1` will be only matching `.`.